# Swift 3 - New UIView not displaying after removing previous one

Tags: swift, uiview

I have set up a simple demo to explain my problem. I have 2 functions. 1 to load a red coloured UIView, and one to delete the current UIView and replace it with a new one at a different X position. I know I can just change the x position of the current UIView but that isn't the point.

I also require an array to store the UIView in, which I am creating like so:

`var cellArray = Array<UIView>()`

The first function to load the UIView is as follows:

```
func loadGridCell(xPos:Int) {
    let cell = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: xPos, y: 20, width: 20, height: 20))

    cell.layer.borderWidth = 1
    cell.layer.borderColor = UIColor(red:1.00, green:0.00, blue:0.00, alpha:0.90).cgColor
    cell.backgroundColor = UIColor(red:1.00, green:0.00, blue:0.00, alpha:0.5)

    self.view?.addSubview(cell)
    cellArray.append(cell)
    print("Spawning Cell")
}
```

This function works perfectly and creates the red UIView. The second function is as follows:

```
func loadNextCell() {
    print("Removing Current Cell")

    for element in cellArray {
        element.removeFromSuperview()
    }

    cellArray.removeAll()

    print("Creating New Cell")
    loadGridCell(xPos: 40) //This should create a new UIView with an x-position of 40
}
```

This function is also working fine up until it attempts to call the first function again with a different X position. It removes the first UIView perfectly fine but doesn't seem to want to create the next. The strangest part is, the function is getting called, and the text "Spawning Cell" is displaying, which tells me that the new UIView is getting created but something is stopping it from being displayed.

What could be causing this?

Comment: Do you call the method `loadNextCell` on main thread?

Comment: I am fairly new to Swift and iOS development and don't know what exactly that means. All I know is the loadNextCell function is being called from when the user swipes down which is coming from a swipeGesture in the GameViewController.swift, however the loadNextCell and loadGridCell functions are in the GameScene.swift file. Sorry if I couldn't be of more assistance.

Answer (score 0):

I did try your code with a simple setup for two buttons, It works properly. Iam attaching the screen shot of the result.Button 'Add all views' adds about three view on the screen, ie I call the code in loadGridCell(xPos:Int) supplying it different values for the X position. 'Button' deletes all the added views, calling the code in loadNextCell(). Can you provide more information as to how the flow happens at your end. Also it will be helpful if you can attach a screenshot of the View Debugger that xcode provides. It shows you the hierarchy of the views that have been laid out
[image: Added all the views]
[image: After removing all views and adding just one view]